# In MDN setInterval example how does var intervalID work?

Tags: javascript, firefox, setinterval

This is the Mozilla Developer Network example of window.setInterval

```
var intervalID = window.setInterval(func, delay[, param1, param2, ...]);
var intervalID = window.setInterval(code, delay);
```

(which can be found here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.setInterval)

I'm more used to compiled Java programming of these types of algorithms so my question is:

How does intervalID work? It seems that there is some kind of recursive function going on there behind the scenes but that's a complete guess - how is it structured and is that structure (presumably quite large) stored as intervalID, waiting for `clearInterval(intervalID)`?

Comment: its all thoroughly explained on the link you sent. No recursion here just an interval between calling the same function repeatedly

Comment: The `intervalID` is just an opaque identifier that lets you call `clearInterval` on a specific timer. It's just a number.

Comment: lol, OK simple as that then! Thanks to you both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm just going to assume that you want to know how it works in the Firefox browser (each browser has its own implementation of the same method). The implementation can be found in [nsGlobalWindow::SetTimeoutOrInterval()](http://hg.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/file/1ee6c61e0a0b/dom/base/nsGlobalWindow.cpp#l9298) and it is actually pretty straightforward. Each window has a list of outstanding timeouts and when you call `window.setInterval()` a new [timeout structure](http://hg.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/file/1ee6c61e0a0b/dom/base/nsGlobalWindow.h#l131) is created and added to that list. The timeout structure contains a reference to the [timer object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XPCOM_Interface_Reference/nsITimer) that will notify the window whenever the callback needs to called. And it has an `mPublicId` member that is simply a number - it gets incremented for each new timeout created and is returned by `setInterval()`. When you call `clearInterval()` it will look up a timeout with matching ID in the list and remove it.

Comment: Great! Was hoping for a 'meaty' response, so to speak. :)

Answer (score 1):

`intervalID` is just a number returned by the `setInterval` function that identifies which interval is going on.

Imagine it as if there was a map of numbers to a tuple of a function and an interval. This probably is not how it's actually implemented, but I think it serves adequately as a mental model of how it could work

```
11: [function () { ... }, 500],
27: [function () { ... }, 230],
875: [function () { ... }, 650]
...
```

Each of the functions in the map will continue to execute at the given interval. If you call `clearInterval` with the id corresponding to an item in the map, it will delete that item and the function will stop executing.